# hdiutil: create failed - error -5342

Tags: macos, travis-ci, hdiutil

I could successfully use `hdiutil` for creating a dmg file on my local El Capitan box, but it's failed with on [OS X 10.9.5 of Travis CI](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/osx-ci-environment/#CI-environment-OS) with the error

> hdiutil: create failed - error -5342

The command used to creating image is

```
hdiutil create -ov -size 512k -type UDIF -fs UDF "$FIXTURE_ROOT/empty.dmg"
```

`$FIXTURE_ROOT` is a exist temp dir. You can find the very details on [Travis Logs](https://travis-ci.org/cybertk/vmdk2dmg/builds/95089045#L1899).

Answer (score 2):

I often had this problem, until I learned (somewhere) that hdiutil often mis-calculates the size, and that causes it to fail. So estimate the size yourself, and double it in the -size parameter. Empty space in a dmg does not increase its size significantly.